# google maps latitude longitude length

Tags: maps

We currently use lat/long stored in our database to display world wide grocery stores with 4 digits to the right of the decimal place (e.g. 36.4488).  We are in the process of updating all records to be more accurate on google maps.  Just wondering if in this process should we extend the lat/long to 6 digits to the right of the decimal place.  Our code would have to change to handle this and wonder if it is really worth the payoff or will 4 digits suffice.  Also, noticed that when displaying marker with position: latlng seems to display in different place than with marker with position: point (where point is set by point = results[0].geometry.location;).  Has any one seen this before?  Thanks for any responses.

Comment: please make your question more clear. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: How much more accurate of a map display will we see if we change the lat/long from 4 digits to the right of the decimal point to 6 digits to the right of the decimal point?  Is it worth the time/effort to modify code to process this change and enter the longer lat/long(s) just to display the marker?

Answer (score 1):

If you use 4 digits to the right of the decimal place, the precision of each geolocated point is around 11 meters. On the other hand, 6 digits gives a precision of 11 centimeters, so if you want the exact location of each store, you should use 6 digits instead of 4.

In response to the second question, if the lat/long of the marker is correct, you shouldn't have problems with it, so review the coordinates of the point.